# Rspec rails TDD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec-rails

What is the best way to configure the rspec with selenium and how to setup test db.

I new in TDD and i am trying to configure rspec by adding the rspec gem in gemfile like

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'selenium'
```

and trying to setup DB like

```
test:
     db_name: xyz
```

but I am stuck as it didn't run successfully. Please guide either I am doing the stuff in right way or have some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this solution manual
add these gems in your GemFile

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'wombat'
gem 'capybara-webkit'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.0'
```

and after that run bundle and to create test envoirment do something like that in your database.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: test_db
```

and then run

```
 rails generate rspec:install
```

this will generate these files.

```
 .rspec
 spec/spec_helper.rb
 spec/rails_helper.rb
```

and to run the test cases use this command.

```
 bundle exec rspec
```

include these in rspec_helper

```
 require 'capybara'
 require 'capybara/dsl'
 require 'debugger'
```

and these in rails_helper

```
   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
   config.include Capybara::DSL
```

then

```
   RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create, db:migrate
```

or 
       RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load

Hopefully this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try google it, there are bunch of links on the Internet that guide you to setup a Rails project with TDD and BDD, here is one of them, my favorite one:

http://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2014/01/04/test-driven-rails-part-1/